# How do I wrap ngx-monaco-editor in a ControlValueAccessor component

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor, ngx-monaco-editor

I am trying to use [ngx-monaco-editor github](https://github.com/atularen/ngx-monaco-editor) for a simple faas application and am trying to enable it to be used within a FormGroup.

This is how my component looks like:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-editor-wrapper',
    template: `<ngx-monaco-editor [options]="editorOptions" [(ngModel)]="value" ></ngx-monaco-editor>`,
    styleUrls: ['./editor-wrapper.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => EditorWrapperComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class EditorWrapperComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild(EditorComponent) editorComponent: EditorComponent;

    editorOptions: any;
    value: string;
    disabled: boolean;

    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log(this.editorComponent);
    }

    //#region ControlValueAccessor
    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        this.value = obj;
       // this.editorComponent is undefined
        this.editorComponent.writeValue(obj);
    }
    onChange: () => {};
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
       // this.editorComponent is undefined
        this.editorComponent.registerOnChange(fn);
    }
    onTouched: () => {};
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
       // this.editorComponent is undefined
        this.editorComponent.registerOnTouched(fn);
    }
    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }
   //#endregion

   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
       // this works fine
        console.log(this.editorComponent);
    }
}
```

And I receive the following error:
[image]

I am trying to do this so that I can use EditorWrapperComponent within a form with formControlName attached to it but cannot figure out how to fix this. If this is not the right way of using ngx-monaco-editor within a form I open to suggestions.

Comment: Do you need that this.editorComponent.writeValue call..? I’d expect setting this.value should be enough. Problem is that this.editorComponent just doesn’t exist it when writeValue is called

Comment: @MikeOne Well yes removing those calls does get rid of the exception. I do see the value in the editor when I change it programmatically e.g. new FormControl('placeholder') but if I were to change it in the browser then I do not see the new value with formcontrol.value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. It seems that all that was needed to be done was

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.editorComponent.registerOnChange(this.onChange);
    this.editorComponent.registerOnTouched(this.onTouched);
}
```

this.onChange and this.onTouched are variables where I stored onTouched and onChange functions provided  by the ControlValueAccessor.

Comment: Any chance you'd be able to post a working sample for the whole component?